# How can I re-acquire the final power?

Tags: infamous-second-son

I've acquired the final power, concrete, upon the completion of the main scenario. When running around in the post-game, I switched away to another power and can't figure out how to get concrete back. How can I switch back to concrete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't get concrete from the environment. You need to find any enemy that has concrete powers (e.g. DUP soldiers), then kill or subdue them. Once they're down for the count, stand over their body and you should receive a prompt to Drain Concrete.

Comment: That would be correct.